# Tikz: Better way to draw this simple diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to draw something like this diagram in Ti*k*Z. My code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (wrijving)                           {wrijving};
    \node (lading)   [right=of wrijving]       {(onzichtbare) lading};
    \node (elkracht) [below=of lading]         {elektrische kracht};
    \node (afst)     [below left=of elkracht]  {afstoten};
    \node (aantr)    [below right=of elkracht] {aantrekken};

    \path (wrijving) edge[->] (lading)
          (lading)   edge[->] (elkracht)
          (elkracht) edge[-] (afst)
                     edge[-] (aantr);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which gives this:
[image: Diagram]

Probably there's a better way to draw this, but I don't know how.

I also want "afstoten" and "aantrekken" to be closer. I know you can specify a value to `below` and `left`, but is is possible to have a branch with normal length, and just rotate it x deg?

Comment: Maybe look at the `chains` library?

Comment: @cfr Or the `forest`? `:-)` I think `forest` is the easiest!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since it's a tree, here's a possibility using the [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package; the code is considerably shorter now and you have the desired control over the separation of the two lower elements using, for exmaple, the `calign` options (see lines commented out in my example code):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={edge={->},
%calign=fixed edge angles,
%calign primary angle=-40,calign secondary angle=40
}
[wrijving,grow=0
  [(onzichtbare) lading
    [elektrische kracht    
      [afstoten]
      [aantrekken]
    ]
  ]    
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This does not yet adjust the positioning but is more concise:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=main going right, every on chain/.append style={join}, every join/.append style={->}]
    \node [on chain] (wrijving) {wrijving};
    \node [on chain] (lading) {(onzichtbare) lading};
    \node [on chain=main going below] (elkracht) {elektrische kracht};
    {[start branch=split going below left]
      \node [on chain] (afst) {afstoten};}
    \node [on chain=main going below right] (aantr) {aantrekken};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: chains]

## EDIT

To alter the compactness of the diagram when it branches, you can specify a more detailed direction for the chain. For example, using the `calc` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes,calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=main going right, every on chain/.append style={join}, every join/.append style={->}]
    \node [on chain] (wrijving) {wrijving};
    \node [on chain] (lading) {(onzichtbare) lading};
    \node [on chain=main going below] (elkracht) {elektrische kracht};
    \node [on chain={main placed {at=($(\tikzchainprevious.south)+(-50:1.5)$)}}] (aantr) {aantrekken};
    {[start chain=split]
      \chainin (elkracht);
      \node [on chain=placed {at=($(\tikzchainprevious.south)+(-130:1.5)$)}] (afst) {afstoten};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tweaked direction]

Note that I'm a big fan of `forest` and, if your diagrams are really trees, it is great. If not - that is, if they change direction many times and do not necessarily have single roots - then `forest` is still an option, but `chains` may be easier for simple cases, where programmatic power is not a significant consideration.

Answer (score 7):

I present an alternative, more concise solution using the `tikz-cd` package that was made for commutative diagrams and has (in my opinion) very clear and simple syntax. With a bit of naive trickery, the spacing is also easily adjusted to yield whatever one likes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
    \mathrm{wrijving} \arrow[rr]& &[-2cm] \mathrm{(onzichtbare)\ lading} \arrow[d] &[-2cm]\\
    & & \mathrm{elektrische\ kracht}\arrow[dl, no head]\arrow[dr, no head]\\
    & \mathrm{afstoten} & & \mathrm{aantrekken}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following:

[image]